# Strongswan forwarding traffic between two IPsec tunnels

Tags: linux, vpn, forwarding

Given a remote (centralized) VPN server with a StrongSwan IKEv2 setup with external static IP:

- centralized server internal IP 192.168.1.65, network 192.168.1.64/27

And two gateways doing NAT for internal networks:

- first gateway internal IP 192.168.1.33, network: 192.168.1.32/27;
- second gateway internal IP 192.168.1.1, network: 192.168.1.0/27;

Gateways are connected to centralized server also using StrongSwan.

Connection works perfectly from gateways to server and from server to gateways: ping works, access to services on the server/gateways. Devices behind gateways also can access server without problems.

The problem begins when I'm trying to access computers between different gateways.

### Configurations:

centralized:

```
conn base
    keyexchange = ikev2
    keyingtries = %forever
    forceencaps = yes
    compress = no

    left = centralized
    leftid = @centralized
    leftauth = pubkey
    leftca = "..."
    leftcert = centralized.crt
    leftupdown = sudo -E ipsec _updown iptables
    leftsubnet = 192.168.1.65

    right = %any
    rightauth = pubkey
    rightauth2 = psk
    rightca = %same

conn gateway-first
    auto = add
    rightid = @gateway-first
    rightcert = gateway-first.crt
    rightsubnet = 192.168.1.32/27
    rightsourceip = 192.168.1.66
    also = base

conn gateway-second
    auto = add
    rightid = @gateway-second
    rightcert = gateway-second.crt
    rightsubnet = 192.168.1.0/27
    rightsourceip = 192.168.1.67
    also = base
```

gateway-first:

```
conn gateway-first
    auto = route
    dpdaction = restart
    closeaction = restart
    keyexchange = ikev2
    keyingtries = %forever
    forceencaps = yes
    compress = no

    rightid = @centralized
    right = centralized
    rightauth = pubkey
    rightca = "..."
    rightcert = centralized.crt
    rightsubnet = 192.168.1.65,192.168.1.0/27

    leftid = @gateway-first
    left = %defaultroute
    leftauth = pubkey
    leftauth2 = psk
    leftca = %same
    leftcert = gateway-first.crt
    leftupdown = sudo -E ipsec _updown iptables
    leftsubnet = 192.168.1.32/27
    leftsourceip = %config4
```

gateway-second:

```
conn gateway-second
    auto = route
    dpdaction = restart
    closeaction = restart
    keyexchange = ikev2
    keyingtries = %forever
    forceencaps = yes
    compress = no

    rightid = @centralized
    right = centralized
    rightauth = pubkey
    rightca = "..."
    rightcert = centralized.crt
    rightsubnet = 192.168.1.65,192.168.1.32/27

    leftid = @gateway-second
    left = %defaultroute
    leftauth = pubkey
    leftauth2 = psk
    leftca = %same
    leftcert = gateway-second.crt
    leftupdown = sudo -E ipsec _updown iptables
    leftsubnet = 192.168.1.1/27
    leftsourceip = %config4
```

When trying to ping **gateway-second** from computer behind **gateway-first** (source computer IP is 192.168.1.40) and running *tcpdump* on **centralized** server in the same time shows:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.1.1 -n
error : ret -1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:27:49.030650 IP 192.168.1.40 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9721, seq 35, length 64
21:27:50.026652 IP 192.168.1.40 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9721, seq 36, length 64
21:27:51.031805 IP 192.168.1.40 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9721, seq 37, length 64
21:27:52.041165 IP 192.168.1.40 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9721, seq 38, length 64
21:27:53.029530 IP 192.168.1.40 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9721, seq 39, length 64
```

So, according to this log packets are arrived to the **centralized** server, but never forwarded to the **192.168.1.1**.

On the centralized server and both gateways I've enabled forwarding:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Routing table on centralized server:

```
# ip route
default via yy.yy.yy.yy dev eth0  proto static 
zz.zz.zz.zz dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src xx.xx.xx.xx
192.168.1.64/27 via 192.168.1.65 dev eth1  proto static
```

And also route table #220 (VPN):

```
# ip route show table 220
192.168.1.0/27 via 5.189.141.1 dev eth0  proto static  src 192.168.1.65 
192.168.1.32/27 via 5.189.141.1 dev eth0  proto static  src 192.168.1.65
```

Any ideas how to enable forwarding between two different tunnels?

Comment: Can you show the routing table on centralized? `ip r`

Comment: @JosipRodin, updated my question, included main routing table and 220 one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the subnets of the two gateways to `leftsubnet` on the central server. Even though `rightsubnet` on each gateway includes the respective opposite subnet, the traffic selector will be narrowed to what's configured on the central server as `leftsubnet` (i.e. `192.168.1.65`). You should see that in the output of `ipsec statusall`. You may also configure `leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0` on the central server, then it will accept *anything* the gateways propose as their `rightsubnet`.

Comment: thanks you very much. That solved my problem. It was so easy. And I'm feel a bit stupid right now.