# Strongswan forwarding traffic between two IPsec tunnels where one is a host

Tags: routing, vpn, strongswan

I'm facing a similar question as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211410/strongswan-forwarding-traffic-between-two-ipsec-tunnels), but the solution did not work in my scenario.

I have

- a VPN server A with a static external IP address AA.AA.AA.AA, an internal IP of 192.168.1.1 and an internal subnet of 192.168.1.0/24
- a VPN server B with a dynamic external IP address BB.BB.BB.BB, an internal IP of 192.168.2.254 and an internal subnet of 192.168.2.0/24
- a mobile device with a dynamic external IP address MM.MM.MM.MM and an IP of 192.168.250.129 when connected to the VPN

Between A and B the two subnets are transparently routed over the VPN, which works fine.

The mobile device connects to A and receives an IP address from the 192.168.250.128/25 subnet. The mobile device can communicate fine with all devices on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet (and the other way around as well), but not with any device from the 192.168.2.0/24.

On A, I can see the packets arriving:

```
hanjo@A:~$ sudo tcpdump -n net 192.168.250.128/25
19:28:31.367911 IP 192.168.250.129 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 26463, seq 0, length 64
19:28:32.469991 IP 192.168.250.129 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 26463, seq 1, length 64
19:28:33.410002 IP 192.168.250.129 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 26463, seq 2, length 64
19:28:34.389997 IP 192.168.250.129 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 26463, seq 3, length 64
19:28:35.449973 IP 192.168.250.129 > 192.168.2.50: ICMP echo request, id 26463, seq 4, length 64
```

On B, no packets are captured.

Interestingly, sending data the other direction, i.e. from a host on the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet to the mobile device seems to be working better.

Capture from B:

```
hanjo@B:~$ sudo tcpdump -n net 192.168.250.0/24
20:44:27.201713 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 55134, seq 0, length 64
20:44:28.202222 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 55134, seq 1, length 64
20:44:29.202355 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 55134, seq 2, length 64
20:44:30.202603 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 55134, seq 3, length 64
```

Capture from A:

```
hanjo@A:~$ sudo tcpdump -n net 192.168.250.128/25
20:42:28.897441 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 0, length 64
20:42:28.897990 IP AA.AA.AA.AA > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 0, length 64
20:42:29.897510 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 1, length 64
20:42:29.897962 IP AA.AA.AA.AA > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 1, length 64
20:42:30.897469 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 2, length 64
20:42:30.897918 IP AA.AA.AA.AA > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 2, length 64
20:42:31.897458 IP 192.168.2.50 > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 3, length 64
20:42:31.897911 IP AA.AA.AA.AA > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 3, length 64
```

However, as you can see, no echo reply is received.

This is my Strongswan configuration:

A's ipsec.conf:

```
conn B-tunnel
    left=AA.AA.AA.AA
    leftid="@A"
    right=B.dyndns
    rightid="@B"
    leftsubnet=192.168.1.0/24,192.168.250.0/24
    rightsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    keyexchange=ikev2
    type=tunnel
    authby=secret
    auto=route

conn rw-v2
    keyexchange=ikev2
    left=AA.AA.AA.AA
    leftid="@A"
    right=%any
    leftsubnet=192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24
    rightsourceip=192.168.250.128/25
    rightdns=192.168.1.1
    authby=secret

conn mobile
    also=rw-v2
    auto=add
    rightid="@mobile"
```

B's ipsec.conf:

```
conn A-tunnel
    left=192.168.2.254
    leftsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    leftid=@B
    right=AA.AA.AA.AA
    rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24,192.168.250.0/24
    rightid=@A
    authby=secret
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
```

Additional information from A:

```
hanjo@A:~$ sudo ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (weakSwan 5.2.2, Linux 3.10.20, mips64):
  uptime: 7 hours, since Jan 08 14:50:14 2017
  malloc: sbrk 586896, mmap 0, used 376264, free 210632
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 44
  loaded plugins: charon ldap sqlite pkcs11 aes des sha1 sha2 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs8 pem openssl agent xcbc cmac ctr ccm gcm curl attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke vici updown eap-identity eap-md5 eap-mschapv2 eap-radius eap-tls xauth-generic xauth-eap addrblock
Virtual IP pools (size/online/offline):
  192.168.250.128/25: 126/1/1
Listening IP addresses:
  AA.AA.AA.AA
  192.168.1.1
Connections:
B-tunnel:  AA.AA.AA.AA...B.dyndns  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s
B-tunnel:   local:  [A] uses pre-shared key authentication
B-tunnel:   remote: [B] uses pre-shared key authentication
B-tunnel:   child:  192.168.1.0/24 192.168.250.0/24 === 192.168.2.0/24 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
      mobile:  AA.AA.AA.AA...%any  IKEv2, dpddelay=15s
      mobile:   local:  [A] uses pre-shared key authentication
      mobile:   remote: [mobile] uses pre-shared key authentication
      mobile:   child:  192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24 === dynamic TUNNEL, dpdaction=clear
Routed Connections:
B-tunnel{5}:  ROUTED, TUNNEL
B-tunnel{5}:   192.168.1.0/24 192.168.250.0/24 === 192.168.2.0/24
Security Associations (6 up, 0 connecting):
      mobile[55]: ESTABLISHED 104 seconds ago, AA.AA.AA.AA[A]...MM.MM.MM.MM[mobile]
      mobile[55]: IKEv2 SPIs: 4dc26b00764d7fbf_i f00fd36247594b6a_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 106 minutes
      mobile[55]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
      mobile{36}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP in UDP SPIs: c1012a86_i 08a38525_o
      mobile{36}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96, 15163 bytes_i (100 pkts, 66s ago), 55569 bytes_o (78 pkts, 87s ago), rekeying in 44 minutes
      mobile{36}:   192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24 === 192.168.250.129/32
B-tunnel[19]: ESTABLISHED 6 hours ago, AA.AA.AA.AA[A]...BB.BB.BB.BB[B]
B-tunnel[19]: IKEv2 SPIs: 97ef622accd69b0a_i* b1cd574224dcba1c_r, rekeying in 80 minutes, pre-shared key reauthentication in 70 minutes
B-tunnel[19]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/MODP_8192
B-tunnel{5}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP in UDP SPIs: cbd873b7_i cebce241_o
B-tunnel{5}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256, 518363 bytes_i (3670 pkts, 0s ago), 274095 bytes_o (3733 pkts, 0s ago), rekeying in 21 minutes
B-tunnel{5}:   192.168.1.0/24 192.168.250.0/24 === 192.168.2.0/24

hanjo@A:~$ sudo ip xfrm policy
src 192.168.250.129/32 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 2851 
    tmpl src MM.MM.MM.MM dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 36 mode tunnel
src 192.168.250.129/32 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir in priority 2851 
    tmpl src MM.MM.MM.MM dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 36 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.250.129/32 
    dir out priority 2851 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst MM.MM.MM.MM
        proto esp reqid 36 mode tunnel
src 192.168.250.129/32 dst 192.168.1.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 2851 
    tmpl src MM.MM.MM.MM dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 36 mode tunnel
src 192.168.250.129/32 dst 192.168.1.0/24 
    dir in priority 2851 
    tmpl src MM.MM.MM.MM dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 36 mode tunnel
src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.250.129/32 
    dir out priority 2851 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst MM.MM.MM.MM
        proto esp reqid 36 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.250.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 2883 
    tmpl src BB.BB.BB.BB dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 5 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.250.0/24 
    dir in priority 2883 
    tmpl src BB.BB.BB.BB dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 5 mode tunnel
src 192.168.250.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir out priority 2883 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst BB.BB.BB.BB
        proto esp reqid 5 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 2883 
    tmpl src BB.BB.BB.BB dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 5 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 
    dir in priority 2883 
    tmpl src BB.BB.BB.BB dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 5 mode tunnel
src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir out priority 2883 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst BB.BB.BB.BB
        proto esp reqid 5 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 

hanjo@A:~$ sudo ip route
default via AA.AA.AA.1 dev eth0  proto zebra 
AA.AA.AA.0/30 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 

hanjo@A:~$ sudo ip route show table 220
192.168.2.0/24 via AA.AA.AA.1 dev eth0  proto static  src 192.168.1.1 
192.168.250.129 via AA.AA.AA.1 dev eth0  proto static  src 192.168.1.1
```

Additional information from B:

```
hanjo@B:~$ sudo ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.2.1, Linux 4.4.23+, armv6l):
  uptime: 24 hours, since Jan 07 22:19:36 2017
  malloc: sbrk 663552, mmap 0, used 246232, free 417320
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 12
  loaded plugins: charon aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-aka eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam tnc-tnccs dhcp lookip error-notify certexpire led addrblock unity
Virtual IP pools (size/online/offline):
Listening IP addresses:
  192.168.2.254
Connections:
    A-tunnel:  192.168.2.254,0.0.0.0/0,::/0...AA.AA.AA.AA,0.0.0.0/0,::/0  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s
    A-tunnel:   local:  [B] uses pre-shared key authentication
    A-tunnel:   remote: [A] uses pre-shared key authentication
    A-tunnel:   child:  192.168.2.0/24 === 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.250.0/24 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
       A-tunnel[11]: ESTABLISHED 6 hours ago, 192.168.2.254[B]...AA.AA.AA.AA[A]
       A-tunnel[11]: IKEv2 SPIs: 0a9bd6cc2a62ef97_i 1cbadc244257cdb1_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 79 minutes
       A-tunnel[11]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/MODP_8192
       A-tunnel{12}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP in UDP SPIs: cebce241_i cbd873b7_o
       A-tunnel{12}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256, 275930 bytes_i (3754 pkts, 0s ago), 523881 bytes_o (3728 pkts, 0s ago), rekeying in 22 minutes
       A-tunnel{12}:   192.168.2.0/24 === 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.250.0/24

hanjo@B:~$ sudo ip xfrm policy
src 192.168.250.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 2883 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst 192.168.2.254
        proto esp reqid 12 mode tunnel
src 192.168.250.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir in priority 2883 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst 192.168.2.254
        proto esp reqid 12 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.250.0/24 
    dir out priority 2883 
    tmpl src 192.168.2.254 dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 12 mode tunnel
src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 2883 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst 192.168.2.254
        proto esp reqid 12 mode tunnel
src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 
    dir in priority 2883 
    tmpl src AA.AA.AA.AA dst 192.168.2.254
        proto esp reqid 12 mode tunnel
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 
    dir out priority 2883 
    tmpl src 192.168.2.254 dst AA.AA.AA.AA
        proto esp reqid 12 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 

hanjo@B:~$ sudo ip route
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.254 

hanjo@B:~$ sudo ip route show table 220
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0  proto static  src 192.168.2.254 
192.168.250.0/24 via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0  proto static  src 192.168.2.254
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
20:42:28.897990 IP AA.AA.AA.AA > 192.168.250.129: ICMP echo request, id 39774, seq 0, length 64
```

Why would there be an ICMP from the public IP of A to the mobile client when A is simply forwarding B's traffic? What you'd expect is an ESP packet with A's public IP but definitely not an ICMP.

Is there perhaps a NAT rule on A? If so, make sure to use the *policy* module to exempt traffic that matches an IPsec policy from the actual NAT rule. Basically add something like this **before** the actual NAT rule (also explained on the [strongSwan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling)):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.250.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This is it - thanks a lot. I should have seen it from the tcpdump, looks very suspicious now.